No puedo crear proyectos en Android Studio
Buenas, tengo un problema a la hora de crear un nuevo Proyecto en Android Studio, y es que no me deja iniciarlo en primer lugar. Instalé Android Studio, tuve que activar la Virtualización desde la BIOS, y reinstalé el Android Studio como Administrador. Ya he hecho esto ultimo unas 3 veces, ya no me descarga la carpeta SDK, pero no me deja darle a "Next" cuando estoy creando un proyecto. Adjunto capturas de pantalla y el error completo, espero puedan ayudarme (estoy haciendo un curso y mi profesor tampoco sabe que pasa)


java.lang.AssertionError: record(1).fileId(1) != backref fileId(-1)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.AttributesStorageOverBlobStorage.lambda$readAttributeValue$5(AttributesStorageOverBlobStorage.java:916)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.dev.blobstorage.LargeSizeStreamlinedBlobStorage.readRecord(LargeSizeStreamlinedBlobStorage.java:388)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.dev.blobstorage.LargeSizeStreamlinedBlobStorage.readRecord(LargeSizeStreamlinedBlobStorage.java:287)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.AttributesStorageOverBlobStorage.readAttributeValue(AttributesStorageOverBlobStorage.java:914)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.AttributesStorageOverBlobStorage.readAttribute(AttributesStorageOverBlobStorage.java:91)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.PersistentFSAttributeAccessor.readAttribute(PersistentFSAttributeAccessor.java:38)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.PersistentFSTreeAccessor.findOrCreateRootRecord(PersistentFSTreeAccessor.java:211)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecordsImpl.findOrCreateRootRecord(FSRecordsImpl.java:420)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords.findOrCreateRootRecord(FSRecords.java:201)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.PersistentFSImpl.findRoot(PersistentFSImpl.java:1500)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.PersistentFSImpl.findRoot(PersistentFSImpl.java:64)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.VfsImplUtil.extractRootFromPath(VfsImplUtil.java:202)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.VfsImplUtil.prepare(VfsImplUtil.java:178)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.VfsImplUtil.refreshAndFindFileByPath(VfsImplUtil.java:100)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.impl.local.LocalFileSystemBase.refreshAndFindFileByPath(LocalFileSystemBase.java:132)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.VfsUtil.createDirectoryIfMissing(VfsUtil.java:371)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.VfsUtil.createDirectoryIfMissing(VfsUtil.java:365)
at com.android.tools.idea.npw.model.NewProjectModel$handleFinished$couldEnsureLocationExists$1.compute(NewProjectModel.kt:176)
at com.android.tools.idea.npw.model.NewProjectModel$handleFinished$couldEnsureLocationExists$1.compute(NewProjectModel.kt:163)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.lambda$runWriteCommandAction$5(WriteCommandAction.java:364)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction$BuilderImpl.lambda$compute$3(WriteCommandAction.java:166)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction$BuilderImpl.lambda$doRunWriteCommandAction$1(WriteCommandAction.java:149)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:992)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction$BuilderImpl.lambda$doRunWriteCommandAction$2(WriteCommandAction.java:147)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:219)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:184)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction$BuilderImpl.doRunWriteCommandAction(WriteCommandAction.java:156)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction$BuilderImpl.run(WriteCommandAction.java:123)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction$BuilderImpl.compute(WriteCommandAction.java:166)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.runWriteCommandAction(WriteCommandAction.java:364)
at com.android.tools.idea.npw.model.NewProjectModel.handleFinished(NewProjectModel.kt:163)
at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.model.ModelWizard.handleFinished(ModelWizard.java:411)
at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.model.ModelWizard.goForward(ModelWizard.java:339)
at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.model.ModelWizardDialog$FinishAction.doAction(ModelWizardDialog.java:350)
at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper$DialogWrapperAction.actionPerformed(DialogWrapper.java:1818)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2313)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6657)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3385)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6422)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5027)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4855)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4969)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4583)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4524)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2809)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4855)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:794)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:739)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:733)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:97)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:766)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:764)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:763)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:690)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchMouseEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:638)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:592)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.access$_dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:67)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1$1.compute(IdeEventQueue.kt:369)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1$1.compute(IdeEventQueue.kt:368)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:787)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1.invoke(IdeEventQueue.kt:368)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1.invoke(IdeEventQueue.kt:363)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt.performActivity$lambda$1(IdeEventQueue.kt:997)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:105)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt.performActivity(IdeEventQueue.kt:997)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent$lambda$7(IdeEventQueue.kt:363)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:861)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:405)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:207)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:121)
at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:191)
at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:236)
at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:234)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:234)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Dialog.lambda$show$2(Dialog.java:1081)
at java.desktop/sun.awt.SunToolkit.performOnMainThreadIfNeeded(SunToolkit.java:2170)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1041)
at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl$MyDialog.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:737)
at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:462)
at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.doShow(DialogWrapper.java:1685)
at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.show(DialogWrapper.java:1643)
at com.android.tools.idea.npw.actions.AndroidNewProjectAction.actionPerformed(AndroidNewProjectAction.kt:55)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.doPerformActionOrShowPopup(ActionUtil.java:339)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.lambda$performActionDumbAwareWithCallbacks$4(ActionUtil.java:313)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performDumbAwareWithCallbacks(ActionUtil.java:362)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAwareWithCallbacks(ActionUtil.java:313)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.WelcomeScreenActionsUtil.performAnActionForComponent(WelcomeScreenActionsUtil.java:102)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.WelcomeScreenActionsUtil$LargeIconWithTextWrapper.lambda$new$0(WelcomeScreenActionsUtil.java:139)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2313)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:297)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6657)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3385)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6422)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5027)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4855)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4969)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4583)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4524)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2809)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4855)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:794)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:739)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:733)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:97)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:766)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:764)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:763)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:690)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchMouseEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:638)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:592)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.access$_dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:67)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1$1.compute(IdeEventQueue.kt:369)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1$1.compute(IdeEventQueue.kt:368)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:787)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1.invoke(IdeEventQueue.kt:368)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1.invoke(IdeEventQueue.kt:363)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt.performActivity$lambda$1(IdeEventQueue.kt:997)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:113)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt.performActivity(IdeEventQueue.kt:997)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent$lambda$7(IdeEventQueue.kt:363)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:861)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:405)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:207)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:92)
